# Suppose we have unambiguous context-free language, how can we calculate the number of words that can be represented by $n$ terminals?

Tags: combinatorics, formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

I am new to formal language theory, apology if this question seems obvious.
Here are some definitions from formal language theory:

> **Definition**. Let $\mathcal{V}$ be a set of variables (usually denoted by upper case letters), and $\mathcal{T}$ a set of terminals
> (usually denoted by lowercase letters). A context-free grammar
> consists of a finite set of production rules of the form $$ V
>  \rightarrow w_1\left|w_2\right| \cdots \mid w_n $$ where $V \in
>  \mathcal{V}$, each $w_i \in(\mathcal{V} \cup \mathcal{T})^*$, and the
> | symbol stands for exclusive 'or'. We nominate one variable to be the
> starting variable.

> A context-free grammar produces a language in the following way. Start
> at the nominated starting variable, and perform substitutions
> according to the production rules, until the word consists only of
> terminals.

> Using DSV method we can convert the grammar into a system of equations
> by replacing:
>
> - the empty word $\epsilon$ with the integer 1 ,
> - each terminal with the formal variable $z$,
> - each variable $V$ with a function $V(z)$,
> - the or | with addition + ,
> - concatenation with multiplication,
> - the production arrow with $=$.

I am trying to understand the following example.

Suppose we have terminals $\{ a,a^{-1}, t, t^{-1} \}$.

Here are some grammar:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& S \rightarrow \epsilon|A| T, \quad A \rightarrow a^{-3}\left|a^{-1}\right| a \mid a^3, \\
& T \rightarrow a t^2 U t^{-2}\left|a^{-1} t^2 U t^{-2}\right| a t a^2 t^{-1}\left|a t a^3 t^{-1}\right| a^{-1} t a^2 t^{-1} \mid a^{-1} t a^3 t^{-1}, \\
& U \rightarrow t U t^{-1}|T| a^{-3}\left|a^{-2}\right| a^2 \mid a^3
\end{aligned}
$$
The grammar becomes the following system of equations.
$$
\begin{aligned}
& S(z)=1+A(z)+T(z), \quad A(z)=2\left(z+z^3\right), \\
& T(z)=2 z^5 U(z)+2 z^5+2 z^6, \quad U(z)=z^2 U(z)+T(z)+2\left(z^2+z^3\right) .
\end{aligned}
$$
Solving these yields the following rational expression:
$$
S(z)=\frac{1+2 z-z^2-2 z^5-2 z^6+2 z^7-2 z^8}{1-z^2-2 z^5} .
$$

**Question**: How do we calculate the number of words that can be represented by $n$ terminals using the equation? Is it related to the root of the equation?

Any insight would be really appreciated.

Comment: Is it obvious that this grammar is unambiguous?

Answer (score 0):

The function $S(z)$ is a generating function, which means that its coefficients when expanded into a power series are the answer to your question. That is, when you write
$$
S(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty s_nz^n,
$$
then $s_n$ is the number of words with $n$ terminals.

You can extract $s_n$ from $S(z)$ by repeatedly differentiating, then substituting 0 for $z$, then dividing by $n!$.
$$
s_n= \frac1{n!}S^{(n)}(0).
$$
There is also the Cauchy integral formula which allows you to recover $s_n$:
$$
s_n=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{S(z)}{z^{n+1}}\,dz
$$
Here, $C$ is a small circle in the complex plane centered at the origin, oriented counterclockwise, which is small enough such that none of the singularities of $S(z)$ are in the interior of $C$.

Occasionally, if $S(z)$ is nice enough, you can get a closed expression for $s_n$. For example, with $k$ a positive integer, let
$$
F(z)= \frac1{(r-z)^k}\tag1
$$
Then, writing $F(z)=\sum f_n z^n$, you can show
$$
f_n= \binom{n+k-1}{k-1}r^{-(n+k)}\tag2
$$
In your case, you can find the [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) of $S(z)$, which will write $S(z)$ as a linear combination of functions like in $(1)$, and then you get a formula for $s_n$ as the corresponding linear combination of terms like in $(2)$. However, this requires finding the roots of the denominator, $1-z^2-2z^5$, of $S(z)$, so this closed form may involve powers of irrational or complex numbers.